# JQuery Input Selectors - On Change & On Load Selection in One Shot

Tags: jquery, input, onchange, onload

I have a function that changes background colors of an input tags parent (and sibling) based on the selected radio button value. However, I want the same rules to apply on form load for when there are pre-selected input values. How do I do this in one shot?

Here's my current code:

```
    $("input.hvl-radiobutton").change(
    function() {
        if ( $(this).val() == '14999:0') {
            $(this).parents('td.ml-FldCnt').siblings().addBack().css({backgroundColor: "lightcoral"});
        } else if ( $(this).val() == '14998:0') {
            $(this).parents('td.ml-FldCnt').siblings().addBack().css({backgroundColor: "lightgreen"});
        } else if ($(this).val() == '15000:0') {
            $(this).parents('td.ml-FldCnt').siblings().addBack().css({backgroundColor: "lightyellow"});
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a function and call it twice...

```js
function doStuff(inputVal) {
        if (inputVal.val() == '14999:0') {
            inputVal.parents('td.ml-FldCnt').siblings().addBack().css({backgroundColor: "lightcoral"});
        } else if (inputVal.val() == '14998:0') {
            inputVal.parents('td.ml-FldCnt').siblings().addBack().css({backgroundColor: "lightgreen"});
        } else if (inputVal.val() == '15000:0') {
            inputVal.parents('td.ml-FldCnt').siblings().addBack().css({backgroundColor: "lightyellow"});
        };
};
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input.hvl-radiobutton").each(function(){
  doStuff($(this));
 });
 $("input.hvl-radiobutton").change(function(){
  doStuff($(this));
 });
});
```

Comment: Also, depending on how you're rendering the page, it might make more sense to format the elements dynamically server-side, so that you're not having to reformat them with JavaScript when the page first loads.

Comment: It's a SaaS solution and I only have control over the client-side. So far, I am only getting JQuery errors in console using your example. I'll update if I get it to work!

Comment: Sorry please try again...I didn't test the first time around!